# Display text/label after textbox in ASP

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple form in a ASPX page that have a lot of `<label>` and `<asp:TextBox>` pairing that construct the outlay of the form.

I have a requirement to add a string behind the textbox to indicate that the field is compulsory. I'd tried adding either a `<span>`, a `<em>` or a `<div>` after the  field but it will still display the message at the bottom of the textbox.

Any way for me to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I mean right hand side of the textbox, not behind as in watermark. My Bad.

**EDIT for sample code:**
I'd tried all the suggestion but it is still not working, thinking whether it's my code issue or not. Below are my codes:

```
<label>Telephone No.</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTelNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<span class="afterInput">test</span>
```

any pointers? Thanks.

**EDIT for Answer** 
As it turns out the problem lies in the css property. The template that i used has all the input assigned with the `display: block` property, which makes anything after the `<input>` element to be pushed down.

After creating a custom css class with `display: inline-block` and assign to them appropriately, i manage to get the result that i wanted.

Many thanks for the answer provided, especially the `:after` attributes and the watermark attributes.

Comment: you mean add water mark to the textbox?

Comment: sorry not water mark, i mean like a mandatory message, at the right hand side of the textbox.

Comment: can u place the sample code ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/ekWG9/

```
.required:after{
    content: "*";
    color: red;   
}​

<label>A box</label><input type="text" value="Hello" /><span class="required"></span>​

<!-- alternative HTML -->

<span class="required"><label>A box</label><input type="text" value="Hello" /></span>​
```

Using the `:after` pseudo element selector allows you to take the literal content out of the markup (e.g. you don't have to repeat "*" over and over).

You can also use relative or absolute positioning to tweak the location of the content of the `:after` pseudo element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ekWG9/1/

Answer (score 1):

By behind the textbox, seems you are talking of watermark text.

You could use the [TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx) from ajaxcontrol toolkit.

There are also several jQuery alternatives to implement it.

[html5 also has browser support for watermarks](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html):

```
<input name="q" placeholder="Go to a Website">
```

You could add an attribute to your control to that effect.

Comment: And the HTML 5 `placeholder` attribute (Chrome, Safari, FF).

Comment: sorry my bad, i should have mention as right hand side of the textbox rather than behind. It's not water mark that i meant.

Comment: cant you just place it after the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Use css for this purpose:

```
span.clsRequired {
    float:left;
    margin:2px 0 0 3px;
    color:red;

}
```

And your span before text box looks like:

```
<span class="clsRequired ">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you should try something like this

 <body>
  <form id="form1">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>&nbsp;<span>Required field</span>
 </form>
 </body>
```